# No messages transferred to Dominoserver?

Tags: smtp, ibm, ibm-domino, messaging

We have two Lotus Domino servers, both running latest version 8.5.3.
in one of the servers we get the below messages on the server console all the time.
We have no problems with mail routing, evrything is working fine, but I want to get rid of these messages from the console/log.

> 2012-02-16 03:02:39   Router: No messages transferred to
>   DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via Notes 2012-02-16 03:02:42   Router: No
>   messages transferred to DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via Notes 2012-02-16
>   03:02:45   Router: No messages transferred to DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via
>   Notes 2012-02-16 03:02:47   Router: No messages transferred to
>   DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via Notes 2012-02-16 03:02:50   Router: No
>   messages transferred to DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via Notes 2012-02-16
>   03:03:43   Router: Successfully issued a request to push to
>   DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME 2012-02-16 03:03:43   Router: Issuing a request to
>   push to DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME 2012-02-16 03:03:43   Router: Transferring
>   mail to DOMINOSERVERUS/ACME via Notes

any ideas?

Comment: This was a problem with Domino 5, which IBM fixed back then: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086699

Have you tried debugging with DebugRouter=1|2|3 and/or Log_MailRouting=10|20|30|40 ?

Have you already opened a PMR with IBM?

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21086699) technote might explain it

Comment: I saw that technote, but it is old and does not apply to 8.5

Comment: I mentioned it because it might be the loglevel: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2FH_SELECTING_A_LOGGING_LEVEL_5289_OVER.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the notes.ini settings "LOG_DISABLE_SESSION_INFO=1" will disable these (and some other similar) console messages.

I can't test this easily at the moment, but I know it's part of my template for notes.ini settings. Along similar lines, I'd recommend LOG_SESSIONS=0 and LOG_REPLICATION=0.
Unfortunately Domino is still relatively chatty on the console log, but these remove most of the unnecessary stuff.

By the way - I believe that these messages are about Notes mail routing, rather than SMTP.